# Jersey LoggingFeature Without MaxEntitySize

Tags: java, logging, jersey, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard with Jersey. I've created a new `LoggingFeature` to log request/response pairs. The code that [instantiates the `LoggingFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html#LoggingFeature(java.util.logging.Logger,%20java.util.logging.Level,%20org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature.Verbosity,%20java.lang.Integer)) is:

```
environment.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(
            kivasLogger, Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT,
            null));
```

Unfortunately, my payloads are large and what's being logged is being appended with `...more...`, which is not acceptable for my requirements. I need to log payloads of *any* size. Can I just replace the above `null` `maxEntitySize` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or will that, also, not allow the max entity size to exceed the internal threshold?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I arrived at my solution and thought that I would post here to share with others who are encountering this problem.

I found that the `LoggingFeature` class internally uses a [`DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html#DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE) value as the default value of the `maxEntitySize` constructor parameter. This default value is set if the parameter is not set in the constructor, which it wasn't in my question above. In the [current implementation of `LoggingFeature`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.java), the value of `DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE` is 8192. The `maxEntitySize` parameter can be successfully overridden with a value larger than `DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE`. I am currently using a `maxEntitySize` value of `1024 * 1024` without any issues, and the `...more...` appendage is no longer present.

Note, however, that extremely large values such as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` that I proposed above may not be able to be used without incurring a `NegativeArraySizeException` (which happened to me).

So basically, changing my problematic line of code above to:

```
environment.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(
        kivasLogger, Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT,
        1024 * 1024));
```

worked for me, but lines with overly large values like:

```
environment.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(
        kivasLogger, Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT,
        Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

didn't work for me.

Comment: For reading the response, Jersey will internally allocate a byte array of size maxEntitySize + 1. Thus using Integer.MAX_LONG will overflow because of the +1 and result in a negative array length -->NegativeArraySizeException. In addition don't set the value too high because the full array will be allocated